# Am I overusing gradients?

Tags: gradient, critique

I would like to know how this looks and an overall critique, but just answering the question in the title is enough (:

So in this screen the user would select what he wants to advertise, all that is shown is a 'progress tracker' and the buttons which the user will select. Both are made out of gradients, so I would like to know if the gradients are too much, or if I should design it in another way.

This is how it looks:
[image: Screen]

And this is how the animation would look (Colors shouldn't change in the progress tracker, but the effect I am looking for is that the user is kind of 'unveiling' the gradient).

[image]

Edit:

Followed your recommendations, is it better?
I personally really like how the semicircle looks with a part of the icon coming out at the top, but it really doesn't follow your advice of 'enclosing' the icon, does it look good? Will the user recognize it as a button?

[image]

Edit 2:
Changed to circle, and decided to use the brightest color of the 'unveiling' circle at the top as the accent color for every screen (So as you progress through the accent color will get darker, I hope that is understandable).
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not over-using, as the area covered by the gradients is not that large. But i would say mis-using, as these icons do not really need to be gradient filled, as they're quite tiny and you don't want gradients to restrict visibility.

Maybe keep the gradient for the 1-2-3-4 progress bar, that kind of makes sense, but definitely not for the 4 large icons below.

Also, i would totally remove the shadows around the larger icons and maybe try to place these inside a thin circular button-like shape instead. The shadow is really not needed as the icons are sharp enough against the light gray background.

ps. check out the [Revolut](https://www.revolut.com) interface

Comment: re: shadows, i would agree. The gradients don't seem superficial, but the shadows do.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I edited my post, what do you think?

Comment: Better, but i would still make those round. Nothing yells 'button' more than a circular blob. Don't try to reinvent the wheel i guess.

Comment: Makes sense. Edited one more time, I would love if you shared your opinion (:

Comment: Even better now.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem I see with this is that the outline of the buttons is not consistent - which is logical when you have different shapes - but I think adding some basic shape that would enclose the icon (circle, rounded square, ...) would make them look more button like. Especially on mobile where everything is more button-oriented.

As for the gradient, I don't mind it very much. I personally wouldn't use it on the icons and would work on them more in the way stated above. What I like is the idea of 'unveiling' in the progress tracker.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I edited my post, what do you think?

Comment: Yes, the version with the round button works. It's up to you whether to add a bit of a shadow to make it more clickable but now it definitely looks like a button.

Answer (score 0):

If you feel like using the same gradient on each logo is a bit too visually repetitive, then you could simply use the gradient across all icons (as shown) for a more unified feel.
[image]